# Shell Script through history command get the last executed timestamp of a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am trying to get the last timestamp of executed script with below. Through command line it works well but via script it gives the current time. not sure what is wrong here

command line:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T" history | grep -v grep | grep "\/test\.sh -f \input.xml"| tail -n1
```

Ouput: correct timings of script execution

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
set -o history
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T" history | grep -v grep | | grep "\/test\.sh -f \input.xml"| tail -n1
```

Output: script executed time, always the current time

Comment: Please check the script, there is a `|` too much I think.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. there is only one | after grep -v grep. Command is same via script and command line.

Comment: It must be something to do with the [`set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) command. I'd try something else... it's *complicated*.

Comment: @Seamus.. Can you suggest how to get the timestamp of previous executed commands...

Comment: Why do you have the `set -o history` command in your script? What does it add? It seems to be the only diff between what works - and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your history file must recorded with timestamp if you need to view the history with time stamp .
To enable history time stamp add (append)  `export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T"`  to your profile file , it can be `~/.bashrc`  or `~/.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile` (system wide)

You need to re-login to get this settings affected , also  you can only see correct timestamps for new history.

Comment: I did the same, added the export to bashrc and bash_profile and also executed command source ~/.bashrc and re-login. 
I still see this output the same output 
command line : 
330  28/12/20 08:26:09
346  28/12/20 08:49:30
347  28/12/20 08:49:57
351  28/12/20 08:50:45
427  28/12/20 10:54:40

Comment: Also bash_history still shows the old output and does not have a timestamp for each command executed , this is after updating the bashrc file

Comment: As I said , It only give correct timestamp for new history (the commands after the setting changed) , as you don't have time stamp in the old history file  , it is impossible to get timestamp for old history . but this setting will help in future .

Comment: Indeed, after making the settings change I executed the commands again. Later executed the script but see no difference..:(